Можно ли полностью перенести среду PyCharm?
Вот у меня есть какой-то проект, и я, допустим, хочу его запустить на другом устройстве, но на том устройстве может не быть установлен ни PyCharm, ни питон какой мне нужно версии, и чтобы мне можно было сразу перенести все нужные файлы на другое устройство, чтобы можно было без подготовки сразу запустить проект, чтобы все библиотеки нужные были и питон нужной версии?

Непонятно, зачем нужно таскать IDE с проектом, но то, что вы хотите реализуется через контейнеры.

это как реализуется?

Это звучит  почти как "если я захочу помыться у любовницы - как мне перенести свой душ" :) Но используй портабельные IDE (например VsCode) и будет тебе счастье.

@u111, а докер там типа будет установлен?

нет, полностью нулевой комп

В каждом твоем проекте pycharm есть файл pyvenv.cfg и там все настройки к путям python при переносе на другой компьютер тебе нужно чтобы там было как на новом компьютере или другом устройстве все должно быть и тогда все откроется нормально. А все библиотеки у тебя там установлены - главное чтобы был правильный путь к python прописан у тебя
